# Embeded webserver and static html pages

Tags: javascript, html, web-server

I have some documentation in html format with some javascripts inside. The documentation contains sensitive data so it cannot be placed to some publicly accessible web server.
I need to send this documentation to the client.
I cannot send it as a simple zip archive of html and js files because modern browsers has [some security restriction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) and the javascript cannot access additional resource files when the page is loaded via file:// protocol.

So I'm looking for some way how to embed some simple webserver and my web content to one package (e.g. jar file) which can be launched by any BFU and used for documentation browsing on the local computer.

Could you recommend me some software with this capability?